# How to edit vuetify 3 default typography styles?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to edit the default typography of vuetify 3, in which it's defined in a variables.scss file that is shown below inside the package itself.

```
$typography: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'h1': (
      'size': 6rem,
      'weight': 300,
      'line-height': 6rem,
      'letter-spacing': -.015625em,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'h2': (
      'size': 3.75rem,
      'weight': 300,
      'line-height': 3.75rem,
      'letter-spacing': -.0083333333em,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'h3': (
      'size': 3rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 3.125rem,
      'letter-spacing': normal,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'h4': (
      'size': 2.125rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 2.5rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0073529412em,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'h5': (
      'size': 1.5rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 2rem,
      'letter-spacing': normal,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'h6': (
      'size': 1.25rem,
      'weight': 500,
      'line-height': 2rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0125em,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'subtitle-1': (
      'size': 1rem,
      'weight': normal,
      'line-height': 1.75rem,
      'letter-spacing': .009375em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'subtitle-2': (
      'size': .875rem,
      'weight': 500,
      'line-height': 1.375rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0071428571em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'body-1': (
      'size': 1rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 1.5rem,
      'letter-spacing': .03125em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'body-2': (
      'size': .875rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 1.25rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0178571429em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'button': (
      'size': .875rem,
      'weight': 500,
      'line-height': 2.25rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0892857143em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': uppercase
    ),
    'caption': (
      'size': .75rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 1.25rem,
      'letter-spacing': .0333333333em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
    'overline': (
      'size': .75rem,
      'weight': 500,
      'line-height': 2rem,
      'letter-spacing': .1666666667em,
      'font-family': $body-font-family,
      'text-transform': uppercase
    )
  ),
  $typography
);

$flat-typography: () !default;
@each $type, $values in $typography {
  $flat-typography: map-deep-merge(
    $flat-typography,
    (#{$type}: map.values($values))
  );
}
```

What i want to achieve is for example change the h1 size to 32px, so that the default vuetify text-h1 class would automatically get the new 32px value.

I have tried overriding the vuetify classes themselves like (text-h1, text-h2 etc...) but it doesn't work since they all have !important property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create variables.scss in assets like bottom.

```
.v-application {
  [class*= "-h1"] {
    font-size: 32px !important;
  }
}
```

and add this to vuetify plugin.

```
import "vuetify/styles";
import "@/assets/variables.scss" // add after vuetify default styles
```

Comment: Hmm, in Vuetify 2 it was enough to declare my $heading values and they would automatically be applied across all helper classes. Do I understand correctly that now I need to write custom css `.v-application { ... }` to get the same result?

Comment: This seems like an override rather than actually editing the styles Vuetify will use. It'd be preferable to have a more integrated option.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and managed to figure out how to override the vuetify styles.

Put the following in `src\styles\variables.scss`:

```scss
$new-typography: (
  'h4': (
    'size': 0.5rem
    // Other style options
    )
    // Other heading types
  );

@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $typography: $new-typography,
)
```

Make sure to use the `variables.scss` in `vite.config.js` (if you're using vite)

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
      styles: {
        configFile: './src/styles/variables.scss'
      }
    }),
    //...
  ],
  //...
})
```